# Governing equation for white X-ray emission spectra and relation to the BB spectra

Tags: thermal-radiation, x-rays

The white x-ray spectra (bremsstrahlung radiation) when plotted for different incident electron energies in the same graph, looks very similar to the Black-body radiation curve except for starting from a minimum wavelength. Firstly, what is the governing equation for x-ray spectra which explains such curve, and secondly how is it related to the BB curve.[image]

Comment: Those aren't temperatures but incident electron energies. And the wavelength scale on the bottom is opposite to how a black body spectrum is shown usually. And you can look up the equation for brems, such as at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung

Comment: I'm sorry, totally messed up what I wanted to write. @JonCuster

Comment: Well, you can edit your own post so it says what you want it to.